# ModuleNotFoundError at No module named 'validators' | Python-Django virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to deploy my Django app(not an expert with deploying apps) to my Ubuntu server. The app works fine on localhost. I use a package named [validators](https://pypi.org/project/validators/). But, when I try to access the app, it shows the error

```
File "/path/to/django_app//views.py", line 6, in <module> [wsgi:error] [pid 971]
import validators
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'validators'
```

I use `virtualenv` and has installed validators inside the virtual environment. `pip freeze` lists as follows:

```
decorator==4.4.1
Django==2.2.8
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pytz==2019.3
six==1.13.0
validators==0.14.1
```

I tried with root user doubting it is an issue with permissions, but no luck. Can someone please help me with this? I am stuck!

[image: Error Screen]

Comment: Are you sure you are starting your app with python from venv? Perhaps you are using system one.

Comment: What does `pip show validators` produce?

Comment: @NKSM My view function basically redirects to the index page. only from index page calculations happen as per the user input. return render(request, 'app/index.html') is the only line in homepage(request)

Comment: @user5214530 Without venv, pip freeze shows another list. So, this should be showing for venv

Comment: @MattCremeens pip show validators show thisName: 
validators
Version: 0.14.1
Summary: Python Data Validation for Humans™.
Home-page: https://github.com/kvesteri/validators
Author: Konsta Vesterinen
Author-email: konsta@fastmonkeys.com
License: MIT
Location: /app/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: six, decorator
Required-by:

So, it is installed

Comment: It looks like it is installed somewhere not on your python path. If you look at your error message, it is looking for it in `dist-packages`.

Comment: Can you import this one from shell?

Comment: Your python path in your error trace isn't the one from your virtualenv. So you're running your instance on /usr/lib/python3.6, which is the system python. How do you run django on your production instance?

Comment: @dirkgroten How do I change that to the python in virtualenv? I tried to export PYTHONPATH variable in bin/activate. Didnt work for some reason. I have installed django in system level as well.

Comment: @MattCremeens yes right. How do I change it to the virtualenv python?

Comment: You’re not telling us how you’re running your django app. Which app server are you using? Which proxy server?

Comment: @dirkgroten My bad. I am running on apache with wsgi on a linode with ubuntu 18.04

Comment: So show us your mod_wsgi Apache configuration.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you. You gave me the right clue. The issue was with the wsgi script for the app. WSGIDaemon python-path was not to the venv python. Got it fixed.